# Fusion Tables query speed

Tags: javascript, caching, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to implement the autocomplete logics available in the Fusion Tables interface using just client side JavaScript:

[image]

So far I found this, which works great: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/autocomplete

It allows me to retrieve all the values for a property, grouped together, so I can autocomplete them. The issue is that it's **extremely** slow. The query

```
"SELECT 'Store Name', COUNT() " +
            'FROM ' + tableId + " GROUP BY 'Store Name'
```

takes up to 10 seconds to run, each time. This is because my table is quite big with more than 150 thousand rows.

However, the *native* interface from the screenshot above is **dead fast**. I tried looking into the code and see what type of query they were making (maybe they have a cache of these results), but I cannot find anything to lead me to a solution.

Any ideas? My thinking is that if the Google native interface is doing it, then there most definitely is a way for me to do it as well... I want to avoid having to use a third party server to cache these results, that would be an easy fix, and it's not the solution to my problem.

Comment: I doubt that Google is actually using the JavaScript API for their native UI.

Comment: @Odi right, but how do they make it that fast? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think they use something like a nested set and a trie datastructure on the server side. A nested set is fast for queries but not for insertion and a trie datastructure is also fast for text retrieval. I think you can combine the 2 to make a fast look-up.

Comment: And how would I do that using their API?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Fusion Tables but it looks like simple sql? See your example?